# Wordpress Theme Validator?

Tags: theme-development, themes, coding-standards

I'm looking for a Wordpress theme Validator.  Not necessarily something that [validates the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) but more along the lines of adhering to the [Wordpress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) for Theme Development.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Theme-Check plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/).

> The theme check plugin is an easy way to test your theme and make sure it's up to spec with the latest theme review standards. With it, you can run all the same automated testing tools on your theme that WordPress.org uses for theme submissions.
>
> The tests are run through a simple admin menu and all results are displayed at  once. This is very handy for theme developers, or anybody looking to make sure  that their theme supports the latest WordPress theme standards and practices.

Comment: Why did someone down vote this?

Comment: I use TC and [TAC](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [WP-Gear](http://wpgear.org/) provides a link to [wp-phptidy](https://github.com/scribu/wp-phptidy) which was written by scribu ([Cristi Burcă](https://github.com/scribu)), a WordPress.com core developer.